# Wordpress user meta not being passed

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this function I'm adapting to add extra values. It works perfecting with the "LP_LEVEL, LP_SUBDATE, and LP_EXPIRES" values, but the new line `$company = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_company', true );` is not returning a value. I've checked the database and I believe the reference to the _company field is correct. The fact that the other fields work but this one doesn't is stumping me! I've tried various ways of resolving to no avail – can anyone help please?

```
add_filter( 'leaky_paywall_mailchimp_merge_fields', 'zeen101_custom_mailchimp_merge_fields', 10, 2 );

function zeen101_custom_mailchimp_merge_fields( $merge_fields, $email ) {

  $mode = leaky_paywall_get_current_mode();
  $user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );

  if ( !$user ) {
    return $merge_fields;
  }

  $level_id = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_issuem_leaky_paywall_' . $mode . '_level_id', true );
  $levels = leaky_paywall_get_levels();
  $level_name = $levels[$level_id]['label'];

  $created = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_issuem_leaky_paywall_' . $mode . '_created', true );
  $expires = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_issuem_leaky_paywall_' . $mode . '_expires', true );

  $company = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_company', true ); // THIS ISNT PASSING A VALUE

  $merge_fields['LP_LEVEL'] = $level_name;
  $merge_fields['LP_SUBDATE'] = $created;
  $merge_fields['LP_EXPIRES'] = $expires;
  $merge_fields['COMPANY'] = $company;


  return $merge_fields;

}
```

There is function before the above code which works and references the company field, so I just cant figure out why the `$company = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_company', true );` isn't returning a value.

**Full code pasted here: https://pastebin.com/jqkFUjsq**

It's line 132 which has the variable which does not return a value. It's installed as a plugin on a wordpress.com hosted site.

Comment: You can getting all user data and check if exist `company` field. `$all_meta_for_user = array_map( function( $a ){ return $a[0]; }, get_user_meta( $user_id ) );`

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry I've tried to implement what you suggested but to be honest I'm not much of a developer so couldn't make it work. I've updated the question showing another function in the code which references the meta field and works, so it must exist.

Comment: Try `var_dump( get_user_meta( $user->ID ) );` in `zeen101_custom_mailchimp_merge_fields()` and if the output doesn't include `_company`, then the current user doesn't have that meta data.

Comment: @user13828103 this results in "A critical error has occurred on your website". It's wordpress.com so I don't think I can turn on debug mode. The function `zeen101_custom_mailchimp_merge_fields()` isnt displayed on a page, it simply collects the data from the website to be passed to mailchimp.

The WP user displays the `_company` field in the admin, and looking in the database I can see the `_company` value on the user (if that helps to clarify?).

Comment: Is the value saved before it is being fetched?

Comment: @JonChubb, then I guess the meta was renamed/resaved (to `company`?) before it gets to your function or maybe filtered out by a code in the theme or a plugin. You can try directly calling the function like so, in a template file where you can see the output: `$fields = zeen101_custom_mailchimp_merge_fields( [], 'user@email.com' ); echo $fields['COMPANY'];` and if you get the expected output, then the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go off of your pastebin as being more accurate. If that isn't true, then this answer is probably wrong.

In you function `zeen101_custom_mailchimp_merge_fields`, on line 132, you are using a different variable, `$user_id`:

```php
  $company = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_company', true ); // THIS ISNT PASSING A VALUE
```

but your other successful calls are using `$user->ID`:

```php
  $created = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_issuem_leaky_paywall_' . $mode . '_created', true );
  $expires = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_issuem_leaky_paywall_' . $mode . '_expires', true );
```

You should be able to correct line 132 by changing `$user_id` to `$user->ID`:

```php
  $company = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_company', true ); // THIS ISNT PASSING A VALUE
```

I don't know why the two variables are diverging unfortunately. In line 119 the `$user` variable is created by looking up the WordPress user by email address:

```php
  $user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );
```

I would also recommend that you compare `$user_id` and `$user->ID`, just by echoing them, to see which is the correct user ID to be using.

*Additional note*

If in fact I am wrong in my guess, and those two variables are the same, as @Dmitry said, you can just also grab all the metadata for the user and see if the key exists.

```php
$all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $user->ID );
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $all_meta_for_user );
echo '</pre>';
```

If doing that allows you to see the key you are after, I'd invite @Dmitry to post an answer to receive the bounty.

*Edit*

Okay, debugging further, since you can't output in the hook, you scan stash the output somewhere and inspect it elsewhere. Inside of that hook, add this code which will stash the value in the database.

```php
// We only want to do this once. get_option will return false if it is empty
if (false === get_option('tmp-key-for-debugging')) {
    // Store our value. The last parameter disabled auto load which we don't need
    update_option('tmp-key-for-debugging', get_user_meta($user->ID), false);
}
```

Then on another page that you can see stuff on, once that hook has fired, use this code to dump it out:

```php
echo '<pre>';
print_r(get_option('tmp-key-for-debugging'));
echo '</pre>';
```

When you are done debugging, you can use this to delete the debug value from the database if you really want:

```php
delete_option('tmp-key-for-debugging');
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris Haas – my mistake, I have tried referencing `$user_id` as `$user->ID` as per the other variables in the `zeen101_custom_mailchimp_merge_fields` function but it didnt work either. I switched it to that to try and replicate the working examples from the other functions which manage to access the value. I struggle with the `echo` option as the function doesn't put anything out on the page, it just sends the data to be passed to mailchimp, so not sure where Id be able to view it? The site is on wordpress.com, not locally so hard to test!

Comment: You're right that they get the user by different means – the code is a combination of two sets of functions provided as examples by the creators of Leaky Paywall and I figured best to stick to how they reference things

Comment: @JonChubb, I have added some updated code to stash the value in the database in order to inspect it on a page that you can actually see output on later.

Comment: Chris – thanks for this I will give it a try. Appreciate your help, bounty awarded :)